# Rspec expect to change not returning the correct result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can't figure out why the rspec expect to change matcher is not working, even though I replicated the logic and I am certain the code is correct.

Here's what I have:

```
class SubscriptionItem < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :create_customer_quotas, on: :create

  def create_customer_quotas
    CustomerQuotaService.create_from_subscription_item! self
  end
```

```
  def self.create_from_subscription_item!(subscription_item)
    customer = subscription_item.customer
    subscription_item.quotas.each do |quota|
      CustomerQuota.find_or_create_by! quota:, subscription_item:, customer:
    end
  end
```

In my test, I have this:

```
expect { subscription.save! }.to change(CustomerQuota, :count).by(subscription.quotas.count)
```

and I get this failure:

```
expected `CustomerQuota.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

However, when I replicate the expect to change logic in the test like so:

```
        count_before = CustomerQuota.count
        subscription.save!
        count_after = CustomerQuota.count

        puts "before=#{count_before} && after=#{count_after}"
```

the output is:
`before=0 && after=1`

So it's clearly working. Why is the expect to change not working as expected?

Comment: Could you please check with passing in block {...} => `expect { subscription.save! }.to change { CustomerQuota.count }.by(subscription.quotas.count)`

Comment: Yep I tried that actually and it produced the same result. It’s just a syntax difference.

Comment: check with replacing `CustomerQuota.count` to `CustomerQuota.reload.count`

Comment: whenever I face this type of problem, I throw in a sleep, like `expect{ subscription.save!; sleep(1)}.to ...etc` to see if it's a timing problem

Comment: I tried reload.count as well.

Comment: @MatthewBerman which rails version you are using?

Comment: I am using rails 7+

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is due to `after_commit` callback, as it dosen't triggered in rspec if we use transactional fixtures.

We need to trigger after_commit callback manually via `ar_object.run_callbacks(:after_commit)`

```rb
expect { subscription.save!; subscription.run_callbacks(:after_commit) }.to change(CustomerQuota, :count).by(subscription.quotas.count)
```

OR you can use the [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem, which would hook up the after_commit callback as soon as transaction is committed. Bundling this gem would do run after_commit callback automatically without any manual trigger. This will be no longer needed on rails 5.0+

Comment: I tried this and and got an error: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass....if callbacks.empty?

Also, I'm already using rails 7+.

Comment: @MatthewBerman Can you make a new sample app to address the above - mentioned issue? Otherwise, it would be helpful if you could offer additional information regarding the `CustomerQuota` and `SubscriptionItem` model schema, so that I can try out on my local.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want (or you can't) to change code, just go with Sampat Badhe answer (use `test_after_commit` or upgrade to rails >= 5.0.0) and stop reading this: This answer is about software architecture and not about solving your rspec problem.

But what I wonder is.... is it really needed to be done in an `after_commit` callback? What if `CustomerQuotaService.create_from_subscription_item! self` fails? You already have committed your `SubscriptionItem` to the database.

You could change the callback to `before_create :build_customer_quotas`
and in your `CustomerQuotaService` call <strike>find_or_initialize</strike> `build` instead of `find_or_create`.

This would ensure everything is in one transaction and would be properly saved or rollbacked.

Update:

Some code that might work:

```rb
class SubscriptionItem < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :build_customer_quotas

  def build_customer_quotas
    quotas.each do |quota|
      customer_quotas.build quota: quota, customer: customer
    end
  end
end
```

The `customer_quotas` will be saved automatically by rails when it saves the `subscription_item` itself. No extra `save` calls are needed.

Notes:

- as `build_customer_quotas` is called `before_create` you don't need to check the existence of existing `customer_quotas`
- you don't mention how you create the `quotas` that you are iterating from in your service. You can use a similar technique to build them and had them linked in your `subcription_item` object in memory.

Comment: This is interesting. I tried this but if I'm just doing `find_or_initialize`, when does the save for `customer_quota` actually happen? The way you described doesn't actually save the `customer_quota`.

Comment: I'll elaborate a better answer on monday. Probably objects created by CustomerQuotaService are not attached to the customer_quota using find_or_initialize. It will definitely work with build, and rails will take care of saving everything within a single transaction. Check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html